# Object.const_set using variable

Tags: ruby, variables, constants

I'm trying to 'name' a new class, using i varaible.

From antoher thread i got som starters regarding the use och 'const_set', 
and it works fine while i try this:

```
name = "Person"
attributes = [:fname, :age]

klass = Object.const_set name, Struct.new(*attributes)

p = Person.new("John Doe", 42) # => #<struct Person name="John Doe", age=42>
```

But now i'd like to use the 'name'-varible a bit differently, like changing the value it holds, etc. (which actually will be a Constant..?)

I'm retreiving a new value externally to a string called titleString..

But when i try to pass it's value to 'name'

```
name = "#{titleString}"
attributes = [:fname, :age]

klass = Object.const_set name, Struct.new(*attributes)
```

i end up with an "wrong constant name"-error..

How come?

Comment: I pasted this into irb and it worked fine for me... assuming titleString was set first, of course.   makes no difference if you say `name="#{titleString}"` or `name=titleString` or `name=something_that_can_make_a_string.to_s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting titleString from an input such as gets?  There may be a newline hanging out at the end of titleString.

```
> name="Bar\n"
=> "Bar\n" 
> klass = Object.const_set name, Struct.new(*attributes)
  NameError: wrong constant name Bar
```

Comment: Ah, that could be it. Thanks.

Comment: Correct, with whitespaces removed it works out fine.

AAH! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would be easier if you print out the value of `name` before calling `const_set`. My guess it's that name doesn't start with an uppercase letter. Constanst must start with uppercase.

Comment: Nope, as a first i'm using the same value: "Person".

Comment: My problem was that I was getting the name of another class and appending a string.  The class name I started with had a namespace, and I cannot use a namespace for this.